# How to terminate multiprocessing Process on timeout

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The multiprocessing `proc` is terminated here using `proc.terminate()` command after 5 seconds the `proc` is started. I am using `while proc.is_alive()` loop to make things done. I wonder if there is another way to terminate proc on timeout.

```
import time, multiprocessing

def process():
    while True:
        print '...sleeping %s' % time.time()
        time.sleep(1)

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process)
proc.start()

timeout = 5
start_time = time.time()
while proc.is_alive():
    if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
        print 'terminating proc on timeout'
        proc.terminate()
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### edited later: this question was marked as duplicate pointing to another post that discusses the multiprocessing.Process's `terminate` and `join` methods. It does not discuss the termination on timeout.

Comment: The post you mentioned here as a possible duplicate cannot answer my question which was "How to terminate multiprocessing Process on timeout".  If you disagree, please copy/paste that portion of the post that explains how to terminate the process on a timeout value.

Comment: Your acceptet Answer uses `proc.join(timeout=5)` and `proc.terminate()` afterwards. Feel free to do so, but using `.terminate()`, which means **`kill`** is bad practice.

Comment: The question was "how to terminate the process on timeout". How "good" or "bad" the `.terminate` method is out of scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Process.join` with it's `timeout` argument to block the calling thread (in your example the MainThread in the parent process) for the specified time. `.join` will await a possible process-exit for up to `timeout` seconds, after which it will unblock. This enables you to write:

```
import time, multiprocessing


def process():
    while True:
        print('...sleeping %s' % time.time())
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process)
    proc.start()
    proc.join(timeout=5)
    proc.terminate()
```

Make sure your process is actually suited for being terminated that way. This means it shouldn't share resources (e.g. queues) with other processes because that will lead to deadlocks when the terminated process holds locks at that moment.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `time.sleep(5)` instead of `proc.join(timeout=5)`?

Comment: @alphanumeric Because `time.sleep(5)` would always wait 5 seconds, but `.join(5)` would unblock as soon your process exits which might be earlier (not in your case but generally).